# How to filter products from product collection which are having custom options?

Tags: magento

I want to get all the products which are having custom options.
Which filter should I use to get only those products which are having custom options?

```
$collction = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct filtering in magento to get the products with custom options.
use the below code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()
    ->join(
        array(
            'opt_table' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(SELECT DISTINCT(product_id) as `opt_product_id` FROM catalog_product_option)')
        ),
        'opt_product_id = entity_id',
        'opt_product_id'
);


foreach($collection as $product) {
    //Load the product if required
}
```

Comment: I am getting an exception: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "6" already exist' in D:\wamp\www\rfg\lib\Varien\Data\Collection.php:373 Stack trace: #0

Comment: @Muk I have updated the answer by using inner query... Might be a bit slower if you have lots of products with custom options.

Comment: Your code is working well now.I have total 43000 products to test.Will this be fast enough in this situation?

Comment: It shouldn't be much slower with 43000 records! Another thing is there is no other option to join these tables without duplicated row!!

Comment: What is the meaning of "Another thing is there is no other option to join these tables without duplicated row!!" ?